# Scheme editing in Emacs - modes and keyboard layout

Tags: emacs, lisp, scheme

Recently I started using Emacs as my Scheme (Lisp) editor. I'm thinking what extensions should I use in order to achieve the best performance. Currently I'm using [Paredit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) and it helps a lot. I know that there are numerous Scheme extensions for Emacs: [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/), [Quack](https://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/) to name the two that seem very popular, and [EmacsWiki lists many more](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Scheme). Which of these have you guys used and which ones do you find the best? At the moment my biggest problem is lack of parentheses colouring, which makes it vary hard to pair them visually - indentations are not enough when you have a line of code ending with ))))))))

I'm also thinking how could I improve the keyboard layout of Emacs in order to do better in Scheme editing? I've found some good advice on [CLiki](https://www.cliki.net/Editing%20Lisp%20Code%20with%20Emacs). I swapped [] with () on the keyboard and that's helpful. I'm also considering swapping [Alt and Ctrl keys](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_kb_shortcuts_pain.html).

Do you have any other tips and suggestions that make it easier to edit Scheme in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [rainbow delimiters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters) mode really helpful for highlighting different levels of parentheses.

Among other modes that help me write lisp are [hideshow mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) for folding of sexps, [slime](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SlimeMode) which is primarily for Common Lisp but I use it's indentation capabilities in scheme too, low-contrast color theme called [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) with which my eyes don't fatigue any more and heavily mutated [vim mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/VimMode) which permits me to keep my keybindings manageable through editing modes.

Answer (score 1):

I use show-paren-mode, a minor mode, with these in my .emacs:

```
(show-paren-mode t)
(setq show-paren-delay 0)
(setq show-paren-style 'expression) ; alternatives are 'parenthesis' and 'mixed'
```

Relevant faces to modify are `show-paren-match` and `show-paren-mismatch`.

It only highlights a sexp when point is immediately before or after it, but I like that it's not so in-your-face.

Answer (score 1):

I use [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/) to get parenthesis right, [show-paren-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode) to see the end and beginning of s-expressions and [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) to mark s-expression (It works on a lot more than that).

Answer (score 0):

I think as you keep playing with paredit you may see less and less need for parenthesis coloring.  For example, type ')' within any sexp, and the opening and closing parens will be momentarily highlighted; then point will move to the end of the sexp.  Being able to navigate the nested sexp structure easily - for example, C-M-u and C-M-d to navigate up and down one paren level - also takes away some of the need to visually pair parenthesis.

Comment: Highlighting parentheses for a moment is only a bit helpful. I found DrRackets highlighting very useful and I'd like to get similar result in Emacs - either to colour the parentheses or to highlight whole sexp.

Comment: @killy Try C-M-u-<space> -- highlights the innermost sexp (and sets it up for killing, copying, etc.)  C-M-u-u-<space> highlights the innermost two sexps, etc, etc